# Passing an argument value from constructor to a function that takes a reference

Tags: c++

I want to write a c++ function and pass it a struct parameter like this:

```
struct vec2 { 
    float x,y;
};

void func(vec2 v);

int main() {
    func(vec2 { 10, 20 } ); // argument value from constructor
}
```

I want my function to take a reference instead but I  get an error.

```
void func(vec2 &v); // reference instead of value
 
int main() {
    func(vec2 { 10, 20 } ); // error: No matching function for call to 'func'
}
```

Is it possible to pass this argument by reference instead of by value without moving the constructor outside of the function call?

Comment: You're running into the issue that [temporaries cannot bind to non-const lvalue references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565600/how-come-a-non-const-reference-cannot-bind-to-a-temporary-object). If `func` doesn't modify `v`, make it take a `const vec2&`. If it does, are you sure it's appropriate to call it on a temporary?